# Xcode Server Bots not running tests

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I'm trying, but failing to setup a reliable continuous integration environment using Xcode server.

I have a git repository on a headless mac mini server running the Xcode server service, the server has a separate development user account with administrator privileges that is used by Xcode.

I have setup my schemes, with testing included and shared them to the repository.

The bots run, check out code, build, analyze and archive, but only seems to run tests when it feels like it, which is almost never.  I've checked the schemes and they have not changed since Xcode ran the tests and when it didn't.

On first setting them up, tests wouldn't run at all, until I added administrator privileges to the development account, then the tests ran a couple of times, before Xcode server decided to stop running them again.

I don't seem to get any reason why the tests aren't run, sometimes the bots fail to run because of some crash during the setup, and an error is reported, but mostly the bot seems to run, they just don't execute the tests, and no error is reported.

I've logged in remotely to the server, and the simulator is running, but never seems to do anything.

Here's a screenshot of an example bot, you can see the tests used to run, it sees I've reduced my warnings and got rid of an analysis issue.  You can also see where no tests run, and no kind of warning or error is given as to why.

[image: Bot view]

I've tried restarting the server, nope.
I've tried restarting the client, nope.

It's really frustrating and can't find any recent issues that offer a proper solution to this. The server is in constant use running backups and other tasks, so I'd rather not have a solution that involves me logging in to the server and restarting something every time there's a problem, which is always, it makes the whole point of bots useless if I'm spending more time logging in to my server trying to get them to work than they are at actually running.

Anyone have similar issues and a solution?

Edit: Noticed that my memory usage was very high on the server, memory pressure was practically always amber, so went out and got some memory today, increased the mac mini's memory from 4GB to 16GB, and now the tests have started running again.  Also, the whole process is much faster (less than surprising i guess).

Could it just be low memory causing problems with the simulator?  I've only just installed the memory and restarted, so I'll give it a few test runs before I confirm this solution, it's stopped working before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this may be a memory issue, I upgraded the servers memory from 4GB to 16GB as my Activity monitor was showing significant memory pressure.

Since doing this, the bots started running tests again, and the total running time for the bot is a quarter that it was.

As per my edit, I've been running the bots for a day now, including bots that run on multiple simulators, and everything seems to be fine.

It's not very good that no obvious indication is given in xcode as to why the tests didn't run.

For reference and to see if this might fix your problems, original server specs were :

- Mac Mini Server edition (late 2012)
- 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- 4GB memory
- 2x1TB drives

Replaced the 2x2GB memory sticks with 2x8GB sticks (The maximum allowed for the model)

EDIT : After a month of running with no problems, increasing the memory has solved the problem permanently.